# cannot find symbol constructor ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,java.lang.String[])

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am extending ArrayAdapter:

```
public class ImgItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageData>
```

I am trying to implement its constructor:

```
public ImgItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] imageArray) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, imageArray);

        inflator = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        imgUrlArray = imageArray;
    }
```

Problem is - when I am trying to compile it is giving me this error message:

```
Error:(28, 9) cannot find symbol constructor ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,int,java.lang.String[])
```

Any ideas?

Here is my source code: [Sample Code](https://bitbucket.org/DaemonConstruction/cosmicreader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `super(context, textViewResourceId, imageArray);` and you received that error meaning that such constructor with the provided parameters does not exist in the super class which is `ArrayAdapter`. Also check the docs to see the correct arguments of the constructors.

Comment: An array adapter does support the above mentioned parameters in it's constructor.

Comment: No, look at his parameterized type. It is `ImageData` but he is passing a `String[]` as the last argument, it should have been `ImageData[]`

Comment: Yep! But it's probable that OP does not know this :)